# runtime complexity linear when suspected n log n

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Having trouble understanding why time complexity of this snippet is O(n)

```
int main() {
  int n = 10; //n can be anything
  int sum = 0;
  float pie = 3.14;
  int var = 1;

  while (var < n){
    cout << pie << endl;
    for (int j=0; j<var; j++)
      sum+=1;
    var*=2;  
  }
  cout<<sum;
}
```

The bisection of var means log(n) and then there is a nested inner loop which apparently has 2n making the overall complexity O(n). But I dont get why 2n.

Comment: The big question is "what is telling you the complexity is O(n)". Are you benchmarking it with a tool, like google-benchmark?

Comment: You can just look at `sum` value at the end of the program to figure it out, because coincidentally it counts the exact amount of  "O(1) steps" your program takes.

Comment: Sure, the `var < n` part is log(n) but the `j < var` part is `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + ..` over all iterations, so it's basically O(n^2).  If you look at that pattern carefully, you'll see it adds up to 2^(n+1) - 1, which is O(2n)

Comment: @Quimby That is how to measure. The question is "Why?".

Comment: CD86, pleae check your formatting. "why 2n" looks like it should be "two to the power of n" in any representation you like ( @paddy e.g. chose the `^` , which easily gets confused with the XOR operator of c++). Please make sure that you do not accidentally ask "Why 2*n?" if you mean "why power of?"

Comment: @paddy While poking at your choice of representation, I still feel that you practically know the helpful answer. Please consider making one with your (sensible) assumptions being clearly pointed out.

Comment: @paddy It's not basically O(n^2) nor is it 2^(n+1)-1.

Comment: When writing exponents in a non-code setting, `^` is commonly used as the representation.

Comment: @user253751 I was thinking 2 ^ (log(n) +1) - 1 ..  thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @paddy you should consider writing the answer. The sum of the pattern `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^t` is `2^(t+1)-1` where `2^t < n <= 2^(t+1)`, so `t` can be approximated to log(n)(base 2). Then the time complexity is O(2^(t+1)) ~ O(2^t) ~ O(2^logn) = O(n).

Answer (score 3):

It might be helpful to consider the case when `n` is a power of 2: `n = 2^m`. Then the number of iterations in the code (which is also, conveniently, the number it calculates) is

```
1 + 2 + ... + 2^(m-1) =
2^m-1 <
n =
O(n)
```

Comment: Better to consider `n = 2^m + 1`, because then for large `m`, the upper bound approaches `2n`. This is still `O(n)`, but is more accurate.

Comment: That would look great in a formal proof, but it requires some "magic" — you choose a particular substitution for reasons which only become clear later. I prefer showing how a normal person could approach the solution.

Comment: Not really that much more complex : `1 + 2 + ... + 2^m = 2^(m+1) - 1 = 2*2^m - 1 < 2n = O(n)`